# using tidyverse and reticulate together crashes R session

Tags: r, tidyverse, reticulate

I'm having the following issue with reticulate and tidyverse together: when I run an Rmd attempting to install both, it breaks R, and I get the bomb error — "R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated."

---

Here's my code:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(reticulate)
library(Rcpp)
reticulate::import("sys")
````

This runs fine. Next code chunk:

````
```{r}
library(deSolve)
library(tibble)
````

where R crashes on the second line.

---

Things I've tried.

1. Running the notebook without tibble --- this works, even with a chunk of python code after.
2. Reinstalling Rccp and reticulate --- this is the solution mentioned in every online post I can find on similar issues. It doesn't work for me.
3. Unchecking reticulate in the package manager --- not sure what this was supposed to do but I saw it online
4. checking reticulate version: I have 1.18. I don't think this is the issue.
5. changing the setup chunk to:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(reticulate)
````

Where it still crashes, but now upon trying to run the python chunk, not trying to install tibble.

6. Removing the entire setup, install reticulate after tibble: same result as attempt five.

---

I don't know exactly where to get the error logs — if they exist — because R studio just dies super hard (I get the bomb). Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know the answer. Your code works fine on my machine, Windows 10,  R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15). I would try to update R and all packages

Comment: (I don't know.) Have you tried temporarily disabling `deSolve`? You seem to be positive it's `reticulate` and `tibble`, have you tried `reticulate` and `deSolve` with no `tibble`?

Comment: Also try reinstalling the last version of RStudio, in addition to R.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I needed to reinstall R and Rstudio, after which it started working again. It wasn't an issue with deSolve. I was avoiding going through the process of reinstalling everything, and I wish there was a better way, but after many hours this is the only thing that worked.